# Printing the URL from Pingdom using Perl

Tags: perl, pingdom

I'm looping through the decoded JSON returned from Pingdom's "Get Detailed Check Information"-API. I'm trying to print the URL in the JSON data, but I'm having a hard time doing so.

Here is the JSON response I got:

```
{
  "check" : {
    "id" : 85975,
    "name" : "My check 7",
    "resolution" : 1,
    "sendtoemail" : false,
    "sendtosms" : false,
    "sendtotwitter" : false,
    "sendtoiphone" : false,
    "sendnotificationwhendown" : 0,
    "notifyagainevery" : 0,
    "notifywhenbackup" : false,
    "created" : 1240394682,
    "type" : {
      "http" : {
        "url" : "/",
        "port" : 80,
        "requestheaders" : {
          "User-Agent" : "Pingdom.com_bot_version_1.4_(http://www.pingdom.com/)"
        }
      }
    },
    "hostname" : "s7.mydomain.com",
    "status" : "up",
    "lasterrortime" : 1293143467,
    "lasttesttime" : 1294064823
  }
}
```

And here's my Perl code that should print the URL:

```
my $decoded_info = decode_json($json) or die "Failed to decode!\n";
foreach my $check( $decoded_info->{check}) {
  print "$decoded_info->{$check}->{type}->{http}->{url}\n";
}
```

I've read the Perl reference and a tutorial but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want

```
$decoded_info->{check}->{type}->{http}->{url}    # ok
```

and `$check` has the value of

```
$decoded_info->{check};
```

so you should be using

```
$check->{type}->{http}->{url}                    # ok
```

instead of

```
$decoded_info->{$check}->{type}->{http}->{url}   # BAD
```

---

By the way,

```
my $check = $decoded_info->{check};
...
```

is simpler than

```
foreach my $check( $decoded_info->{check}) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  I was making this out to be harder than it should have been.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one item inside of the *check*.

```
{
  "check" : {                     // here
    "id" : 85975,
    "name" : "My check 7",
    "resolution" : 1,
    "sendtoemail" : false,
    "sendtosms" : false,
    "sendtotwitter" : false,
    "sendtoiphone" : false,
    "sendnotificationwhendown" : 0,
    "notifyagainevery" : 0,
    "notifywhenbackup" : false,
    "created" : 1240394682,
    "type" : {
      "http" : {
        "url" : "/",
        "port" : 80,
        "requestheaders" : {
          "User-Agent" : "Pingdom.com_bot_version_1.4_(http://www.pingdom.com/)"
        }
      }
    },
    "hostname" : "s7.mydomain.com",
    "status" : "up",
    "lasterrortime" : 1293143467,
    "lasttesttime" : 1294064823
  }
}
```

There is no reason to iterate over anything. You can get rid of the `foreach` loop and simply use the string `check` as your hash key.

```
#                      vvvvv
print "$decoded_info->{check}->{type}->{http}->{url}\n";
```